# Zabbix Web Scenario

Tags: web, zabbix, html

One of my tasks with Zabbix is to monitor the many web applications that I support and gather accurate response times, emulating the user-experience. I have attempted to implement my scenarios based on the [Zabbix Web Scenario section in the manual](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/web_monitoring/example), but I can't manage to get Zabbix to login to the page.

In the Zabbix tutorial, they are using the `name`field in the HTML to designate where to enter the data. [image: Zabbix page example]

On my web applications, this field is present for entering the user name and password, but not for the login button.
[image: My page example]

*How can I get Zabbix to login to these pages without the `name` field being present in the HTML code?*

Comment: Zabbix manual uses http form field, which is defined by parameter "name" (and actual value of this parameter is also"name"). Your snippet doesn't contain name parameter, so it's not obvious which parameters are sent from the form. Could extend your snippet please and show everything between <form> and </form> tags please?

Comment: @JanGaraj Just updated with requested snippet :)

Comment: The button is irrelevant. As shown in the docs, you specify the post variables directly.

Comment: @MichaelHampton So in the case represented in the picture below, what would I put for it to actually login? Currently I specify the username and password, but it does not login.

Comment: @MichaelHampton So is zabbix identifying these fields by id, I just realized I was looking at the code completely wrong.

Comment: No, form input fields use name and value, id is only used for referencing the element in the DOM (e.g. for CSS styling).

Comment: @MichaelHampton So do I even need to worry about the button at all? In the Zabbix tutorial they use it, but I am completely unsure of how to utilize it in my example.

Comment: If your web application does not require the value of the POST variable sent by the button for login, then you don't need to care about it. The best way here is to check your web application which POST variables it uses for login, and set those POST variables in Zabbix web scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem. As per the comments, the button was not actually necessary to submit the content. However, the value of the **name**  field was required for the username and password to submit properly.
[image: Name fields]
The trick was to create a **login step**, with the URL that is called when the form is submitted (in my example it is the *action* of the form).  You need to put your post variables in this step as well, following redirects of course. 
[image: Action]

*For example, using the above pictures:*

- **URL**: `https://www.example.com/nu`
- **Post** (using macros in Zabbix):  `userName={user}&passWord={password}`

Then, I created the **login check** step, which searched for a string that is on the landing page, *and* received a status code of 200.

Once this is working, you know that you have logged in successfully.  Be sure that after all steps you want Zabbix to take, you have it log out.

Thanks for all the help in comments!